# Random number except numbers written in list before

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I know how to get random numbers from, for example, 7 to 14, but is it also possible to somehow get random Numbers from 7 to 14 **except** some numbers from a list written before?

Example:

```
Forbidden = [12, 13, 8, 7]
a = randint(7, 14)
```

`a` should be a random number but **not** the numbers written in `Forbidden`.

Edit: Thanks for the advice, using a while loop or .choice actually solved my Problem. But at the end @user2357112 was right, obviously the Blacklist Idea **is** a Beginner trap, shuffling a deck solved my Problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a number is range (1,n) but not in a list (i,j)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621024/generate-a-number-is-range-1-n-but-not-in-a-list-i-j)

Comment: keep in mind that naming variables starting with a capital letter are not allowed by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45)

Comment: general question of programming/algorithms, not at all related to python, browse through the questions before posting

Comment: Is it reasonable not to think that the "Forbidden" list increases with a new randon number every iteration?

Comment: @IshanSrivastava: the language **is** relevant here. OP doesn't want answers that show code in a language they don't understand. Also, the code posted by OP is Python, and the [python] tag helps with the syntax highlighting. (On the other hand, your duplicate link is spot-on.)

Comment: @CrisLuengo this seems like a design question. once the set of tasks needed to be performed are clear, it can be performed in any language but anyways ...

Answer (score 5):

You know how a real card game prevents you from drawing cards that have already been drawn? It doesn't involve a blacklist of drawn cards. There's a deck, and you shuffle it.

Do the same thing in your program. Instead of trying to maintain a blacklist of drawn cards, shuffle a deck of cards at the start of the program and draw cards from the deck:

```
import random

deck = some_list
random.shuffle(deck)

# when you want to draw a card
card = deck.pop()
```

Comment: no mention of shuffling some collection in the question. just to get a random variable that is not present in a list

Comment: @IshanSrivastava: The questioner is specifically trying to program a card game: "I am pretty much a beginner and am trying to make a cardgame work." This blacklist idea is a common beginner trap that comes up a lot for card game questions, when people want to prevent drawing duplicate cards.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `choice` function:

```
import random
total_data = [i for i in range(1,15)]
forbidden = [12, 13, 8, 7]
not_forbidden =[i for i in total_data if i not in forbidden] #make a list of not forbidden numbers
a = random.choice(not_forbidden) #select value which is between 7 and 14 and not in forbidden list
print(a)
```

Or you can write your own custom function:

```
import random
Forbidden = [12, 13, 8, 7]
def get_number(forbidden_list):
    while True:
        a = random.randint(7,14)
        if a not in forbidden_list: #if this number if not forbidden list then break the loop and return the value
            return a
result = get_number(Forbidden)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `random.choice()` :

```
import random
...
not_forbidden = [1,2,3,4]
a = random.choice(not_forbidden)
```

Comment: Not really, that's why functions such as `range()` exist :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
Forbidden = [12, 13, 8, 7]
a = randint(7, 14)
while a in Forbidden: a = randint(7, 14)
```

Use a while loop to keep getting new random numbers until the number isn't in Forbidden

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't do that in `randindt` command as I know, but you can do it in a `while` loop like so:

```
while a in forbidden:
  a = randint(7, 14)
```